# Finding $\mathbb{E}[X 1_{X\geq \omega}]$

Tags: probability, expected-value

For all $x$, let $F(x) = 0$ if $ x<1 $, $F(x)=1-1/x^p$ if $ 1\leq x < \omega$ and $F(x) =1$ if $x\geq \omega$, with $0 < p < 1$ and $\omega >1$.

Let $X$ be a random variable with cdf $F$.

Could somebody show me how to compute $\mathbb{E}[X 1_{X\geq \omega}] $?

Comment: you are supposed to show your work behind it or else people will vote close your question as per the site rule.

Comment: @nav: start by writing down what $E[X \times 1_{X \geq \omega}]$ means.  Break down the cases -- when is $1_{X \geq \omega}$ equal to 1 and when is it zero?  Integrate.

Comment: @nomen if I do so I shall find $0$, which i find strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint 1: $$\mathbb{E}[X1_A] = \mathbb{E}[X1_A(\omega)|\omega\in A]\mathbb{P}(\omega\in A)+\mathbb{E}[X1_A(\omega)|\omega\notin A]\mathbb{P}(\omega\notin A)$$
by the law of Total Expectation. Now this can be further simplified by just the definition of indicator variable and then by the given CDF of $X.$

Comment: $A=\{X\geq r\}$. Only the second terme remains and $P(X<r)=1$. How can I compute the conditional expectation?

Comment: No, the first term remains and when $\omega\in A,$ the indicator function is simply equal to $1$, so what you need to compute is $\mathbb{E}[X|X\geq\omega]$ and you can compute this directly from the definition of condition expectation. Go take a look at the definition.